# Use Python to write on specific columns in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have data in a file and I need to write it to CSV file in  specific column. The data in file is like this:

```
002100
002077
002147
```

My code is this:

```
import csv

f = open ("file.txt","r")
with open("watout.csv", "w") as output:
    for line in f :
       c.writerows(line)
```

It is always writes on the first column. How could I resolve this?
Thanks.

Comment: 1) That code won't work and 2) You should explain in plain English what you're trying to achieve, as at the moment - it's unclear as to what you're asking/attemping

Comment: You don't seem to be using the csv module, even though you're importing it, and `c` isn't defined. Post a minimal, working example that clearly demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem

```
f1 = open ("inFile","r") # open input file for reading

with open('out.csv', 'w',newline="") as f:up # output csv file
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    with open('in.csv','r') as csvfile: # input csv file
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:  
            row[7] = f1.readline() # edit the 8th column 
            writer.writerow(row)
f1.close()
```

python 2 users replace

```
with open('out.csv', 'w',newline="") as f:
```

by

```
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as f:
```

Comment: This code is for writing in specific rows, isn't it?