# Writing iteratively on .txt file PYTHON

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, header

I have a .txt file (it is the header file of a 3D seismic file) with 90035 lines and 19 columns. Every column represents a different variable (header of the seismic file) and most of them are set to 0.
I want to fill the 4th and the 18th columns:
- the 4th column should be filled with values from 1 to 8185 and again from 1 to 8185 and again repetitevely for 11 times (8185x11=total numbers of lines)
- the 18th column should have values increasing from 1 to 11 every 8185 lines, so that you got 8185 times each value from 1 to 11.
Can you help me? I'm getting crazy with loops

Thanks a lot

here you can find the .txt file:

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/728701/info.txt

Comment: And you have tried...what so far?

Comment: We won't write it for you, there are other sites for that.

Answer (score 0):

The comments here are correct in that you should post some sample code to show the work that you've done.

You can see that it's [kind of annoying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16758596/9458191) to try to manipulate a particular column of a csv. A better solution might be to import the whole file into python and manipulate it in memory. Here we'll use `pandas` to manipulate the whole text file as a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.txt')
df['interesting_columnname'] = [x % 8184 for x in range(0, df.shape[0])]
df.to_csv('new_file.txt')
```